# Error al intentar usar npm start o yarn start en un proyecto nuevo de create-react-app

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, yarn

Soy nuevo en react y tengo problema en la instalacion de un nuevo proyecto uso el comando npx create-react-app my-app --use-npm acepto a cd my-app/ despues npm start y me sale ese error en la consola

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es la imagen no se pudo subir sorry...

Comment: No se ve el error, por otro lado te recomiendo https://codigofacilito.com/cursos/react-profesional es gratis, te va a ser de utilidad. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Encontraste solución alguna?

Comment: Ya intentaste ejecutar el npm install?

Answer (score -1):

La opción a probar sería la siguiente:

Elimina el lock para poder actualizar las versiones de las dependencias que lo necesiten.

```js
rm package-lock.json
```

Borra la carpeta node_modules para tener la carpeta limpia.

```js
rm -rf node_modules/
```

Ahora ya puedes volver a instalar

```js
npm install
```

Y ejecutarlo.

```js
npm start
```

no obstante comprueba que tengas las versiones de node y npm requeridas!